# Spring boot application not using k8 gke service account instead using a default service account

Tags: spring-boot, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-pod

Problem  Statement:

I  have  deployed  a  spring  boot  app  in  gke  under  a  namespace
when  the  app  starts  it  uses  a  default  gce  sa  credentials  to  authenticate.
what  i  did  is  created a  gke  service  account  and  used  iam  policy  binding  to  bind  with  a  google  service  account and  added  workload  identity  user  role
then  annotated  the  gke  sa  by executing   below  2  commands

issue  is  still  my  spring  boot  uses  default  gce  sa  credentials
Can  someOne  Please  help  me  in  resolving  this.

I  can  see  serviceAccountName  is  changed  to  new  gke  k8  SA  and  secret  is  also  getting  created  and  mounted.But app  deployed  are  not  using  this Gke SA

Note:  I am  using  Helsm  chart  for  deployment

```
gcloud iam service-accounts add-iam-policy-binding \
  --member serviceAccount:{projectID}.svc.id.goog[default/{k8sServiceAccount}] \
  --role roles/iam.workloadIdentityUser \
  {googleServiceAccount}

kubectl annotate serviceaccount \
  --namespace default \
  {k8sServiceAccount} \
  iam.gke.io/gcp-service-account={googleServiceAccount}
```

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: helloworld
    appVersion: {{ .Values.appVersion }}
  name: helloworld
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: helloworld
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: helloworld
        environment: {{ .Values.environment }}
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: {{ .Values.serviceAccountName }}
      containers:
        - name: helloworld
          image: {{ .Values.imageSha }}
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          securityContext:
            allowPrivilegeEscalation: false
            runAsUser: 1000
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
          env:
          - name: SPRING_CONFIG_LOCATION
            value: "/app/deployments/config/"          
          volumeMounts:
            - name: application-config
              mountPath: "/app/deployments/config"
              readOnly: true
      volumes:
      - name: application-config
        configMap:
          name: {{ .Values.configMapName }}
          items:
          - key: application.properties
            path: application.properties
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create a pod, if you do not specify a service account, it is automatically assigned the `default` service account in the same namespace. If you get the raw json or yaml for a pod you have created (for example, `kubectl get pods/<podname> -o yaml`), you can see the `spec.serviceAccountName` field has been automatically set.

You can access the API from inside a pod using automatically mounted service account credentials, as described in Accessing the Cluster [1]. The API permissions of the service account depend on the authorization plugin and policy [2] in use.

In version 1.6+, you can opt out of automounting API credentials for a service account by setting `automountServiceAccountToken: false` on the service account:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: build-robot
automountServiceAccountToken: false
...
```

In version 1.6+, you can also opt out of automounting API credentials for a particular pod:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: my-pod
spec:
  serviceAccountName: build-robot
  automountServiceAccountToken: false
  ...
```

The pod spec takes precedence over the service account if both specify a `automountServiceAccountToken` value.

---

[1] https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/access-cluster/

[2] https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authorization/#authorization-modules

Comment: Thanks  for  the  suggestion...its  now  wrking  as  expected